# JanusGraph .graphml file schema issue while creating in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to create schema from .graphml file and using Cassandra as backend storage. I am getting below issue when trying to load data into the schema created for the attached .graphml file. The schema definition is following.

```
    private static void setAirRouteSchema(JanusGraphManagement mgmt, JanusGraph graph) throws IOException {

//        System.out.println("Inside setAirRouteSchema  "+mgmt);
        // Define edge labels and usage
        mgmt = graph.openManagement();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("Frederick Douglass Boulevard").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("West Street").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("North Moore Street").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("Nagle Avenue").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("Broadway").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("Rivington Street").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("West 144th Street").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("[u'River Terrace', u'Vesey Place']").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("Avenue C").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("Division Street").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("Eldridge Street").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("East 79th Street").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("Madison Avenue").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("East 27th Street").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("Hester Street").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("East 81st Street").multiplicity(MULTI).make();
        mgmt.commit();

// Define vertex labels
        mgmt = graph.openManagement();
        mgmt.makeVertexLabel("traffic_signals").make();
        mgmt.commit();

// Define vertex property keys
        mgmt = graph.openManagement();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("ref").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("highway").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("osmid").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("x").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("y").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.commit();

// Define edge property keys
        mgmt = graph.openManagement();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("service").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("access").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("width").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("tunnel").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("bridge").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
//        mgmt.makePropertyKey("ref").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("geometry").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("maxspeed").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("lanes").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
//        mgmt.makePropertyKey("key").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("oneway").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
//        mgmt.makePropertyKey("highway").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
//        mgmt.makePropertyKey("osmid").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("length").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.makePropertyKey("name").dataType(Integer.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();
        mgmt.commit();

}

GraphMl file loaded from here : https://www.kaggle.com/crailtap/street-network-of-new-york-in-graphml

Error :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name cannot be in protected namespace: edge
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.types.system.SystemTypeManager.throwIfSystemName(SystemTypeManager.java:72)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.types.StandardRelationTypeMaker.name(StandardRelationTypeMaker.java:181)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.types.StandardRelationTypeMaker.<init>(StandardRelationTypeMaker.java:53)

Also Schema is being created but data is not getting entered. Printing the schema created:

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Vertex Label Name              | Partitioned | Static                                             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
traffic_signals                | false       | false                                              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Edge Label Name                | Directed    | Unidirected | Multiplicity                         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
East 81st Street               | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
Frederick Douglass Boulevard   | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
West Street                    | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
North Moore Street             | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
Nagle Avenue                   | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
Broadway                       | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
Rivington Street               | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
West 144th Street              | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
[u'River Terrace', u'Vesey Place'] | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
Avenue C                       | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
Division Street                | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
Eldridge Street                | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
East 79th Street               | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
Madison Avenue                 | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
East 27th Street               | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
Hester Street                  | true        | false       | MULTI                                |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Property Key Name              | Cardinality | Data Type                                          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ref                            | SINGLE      | class java.lang.String                             |
highway                        | SINGLE      | class java.lang.String                             |
osmid                          | SINGLE      | class java.lang.String                             |
x                              | SINGLE      | class java.lang.String                             |
y                              | SINGLE      | class java.lang.String                             |
service                        | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
access                         | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
width                          | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
tunnel                         | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
bridge                         | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
geometry                       | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
maxspeed                       | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
lanes                          | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
oneway                         | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
length                         | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
name                           | SINGLE      | class java.lang.Integer                            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Vertex Index Name              | Type        | Unique    | Backing        | Key:           Status |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Edge Index (VCI) Name          | Type        | Unique    | Backing        | Key:           Status |
----------------------------------
```

### -----------------------------------------------------------------

Relation Index                 | Type        | Direction | Sort Key       | Order    |     Status |

Comment: I'm not clear as to when you're getting this error. Is it on schema creation or during loading of the graphml? if it's happening during loading, what is the code you're using to load it - standard `io()` functions in Gremlin?

Comment: Schema creation is fine. The error is while loading data from graphml. Code to load includes these steps:                                                                                           1. JanusGraph graph = JanusGraphFactory.open("src/main/resources/janusgraph-cassandra.properties");                                                                                         2. JanusGraphManagement mgmt = graph.openManagement();                               3. setAirRouteData(graph);

Comment: setAirRouteData(graph) implementation as-->  private static void setAirRouteData(JanusGraph graph) throws IOException {
        graph.io(graphml()).readGraph("/src/main/java/../../../0184096_York.graphml");
        graph.tx().commit();
    }

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the problem but that GraphML does not include the expected edge and vertex labels that the TinkerPop `GraphMLReader` expects (i.e. `labelE` and `labelV` respectively). You can either adjust your data or configure the `GraphMLReader` to use a property key in your data that you specify via the `GraphMLReader.Builder.edgeLabelKey()` and `vertexLabelKey()`. You can see those and other configurations in the [javadoc](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/io/graphml/GraphMLReader.Builder.html).

I think you want to do something like:

```
GraphMLReader reader = GraphMLReader.build().edgeLabelKey(<whatever your label field is>).create();
InputStream input = FileInputStream(<path to graphml file>);
reader.readGraph(input, graph);
```

Note that if you're using newer version of TinkerPop, you can just use Gremlin with:

```
GraphMLReader reader = GraphMLReader.build().edgeLabelKey(<whatever your label field is>).create();
g.io(<path to graphml file>).
    with(IO.reader, reader).
    read().iterate()
```

Comment: thanks for that. Following that,  I did :  ``` GraphMLReader reader = GraphMLReader.build().edgeLabelKey("labelE").vertexLabelKey("labelV").create();
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("src/main/java/com/../../Manhattan.graphml");
        reader.readGraph(input, graph);
        graph.tx().commit(); ``` However still gives ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name cannot be in protected namespace: edge```

Comment: "edge" is a reserved word in JanusGraph (as are some others - full  list is: "key", "vertex", "edge", "element", "property", "label") and you get that error if you try to use any of those, but I don't see where you're doing that anywhere. Perhaps you should check your code locally to validate that "edge" is not being used somehow? https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/6998664aae0de0fd10d0a9609782e98351d9f3b0/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/graphdb/types/system/SystemTypeManager.java#L55

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I’m getting the same error despite also not using “edge” anywhere.